# python.exe running slower is custom Anaconda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, environments

Can't find anyone else having the same problem as me online so here we go.

I have Anaconda installed at work on my C: drive, but for certain reasons I now need to setup an environment on a shared network drive. To do this I ran the following in Anaconda prompt:

```
conda create -n "M:\path\to\envFile" --no-default-packages python pyodbc xlwings ... ect

activate "M:\path\to\envFolder"
```

No problems so far! Some other people use my programs by running batch files e.g:

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe M:\path\to\pythonFile.py
```

Once my environment was setup I tried running some code calling the python.exe in my new environment i.e.

```
M:\path\to\envFolder\python.exe M\path\to\pythonFile.py
```

However the second method (using the environment python.exe) takes 120 seconds just to print "Hello world!"

Seems like there's a lot more going on when I run from my environment but I don't have any idea what it is! Any information on what might be happening would be super useful. Ultimately I would like to be able to run my python from my new environment without the 2 minute wait!

Thanks in advance for any help!